# VueJS transition on enter and leave

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to learn VueJS and currently unable to resolve this problem with transitions. I have two components called `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` like this:

ComponentA:

```
<template>
<div id="ComponentA">
    <h1 class="header" v-on:click="update">HEADER</h1>
    <transition
        name="custom-classes-transition"
        enter-active-class="animated fadeInDown"
        leave-active-class="animated fadeOutUp"
    ><p class="content" v-if="visible">
        Some information...
    </p></transition>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import App from "@/App";

export default {
    datas: {
        visible: false
    },
    name: "ComponentA",
    data () {
        return this.$options.datas;
    },
    methods: {
        update () {
            App.update(this.$options.name);
        }
    }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

ComponentB:

```
<template>
<div id="ComponentB">
    <h1 class="header" v-on:click="update">HEADER2</h1>
    <transition
        name="custom-classes-transition"
        enter-active-class="animated fadeInDown"
        leave-active-class="animated fadeOutUp"
    ><p class="content" v-if="visible">
        Some more information...
    </p></transition>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import App from "@/App";

export default {
    datas: {
        visible: false
    },
    name: "ComponentB",
    data () {
        return this.$options.datas;
    },
    methods: {
        update () {
            App.update(this.$options.name);
        }
    }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

And this is my App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <header href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <ComponentA />
      <ComponentB />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ComponentA from "@/components/ComponentA";
import ComponentB from "@/components/ComponentB";

export default {
    name: "App",
    components: {
        ComponentA,
        ComponentB
    },
    update (clickedComponent) {
        for (let component in this.components) {
            component = this.components[component];

            if (component.name === clickedComponent) {
                component.datas.visible = !component.datas.visible;
            } else {
                component.datas.visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
};
</script>

<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Space+Mono');

:root {
    --background: #0f0f0f;
    --blueish: #546a76;
    --grayish: #7c7c7c;
    --lighterblueish: #737c81;
}

body {
    line-height: 1.7;

    background-color: var(--background);
    color: var(--grayish);

    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;

    height: 100%;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 10vh;
}

.header {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

    color: var(--blueish);
    width: max-content;
    position: sticky;
    left: 100%;
}

.header span {
    background-color: var(--lighterblueish);
    color: var(--background);
}

.content {
    padding-top: 5%;
}

.content span {
    color: var(--blueish);
}
</style>
```

So the problem is when I click on the ComponentA's header, its "content" fades in with a nice smooth animation and ComponentB moves down but without any transition. I'm unable add transition to ComponentB's movement. It just immediately jumps down. I tried adding keys, giving transition to everything on body but none of these worked. I need to somehow add transition to ComponentB's movement.

Edit: JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/44ctt020/2/

Comment: Could you add a working code example? Perhaps a JSFiddle.

Comment: Took me a while but managed: https://jsfiddle.net/44ctt020/2/

Oh, some css stuff is not working (like max-content and sticky position) but I don't think they are relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you are using [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) for your animation. If you check the source, the animation `fadeInDown` is defined by keyframes using these properties:

```
0% {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}
100% {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: none;
}
```

The `translate3d` moves the content of your element independently of the reserved space on the page. You can see that in this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WMJjMO.

So as soon as you show component A, it takes up the required space on the page and pushes component B down *immediately* and *then* animates its content.

To achieve the effect you describe, you will have to animate the height of your content element. That will make the other component move up or down accordingly.

I recommend reading this Vue guide and define a custom transition on the CSS properties opacity and height: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

Comment: I get it. So animate.css is not actually applying any transitions but just an animaton... I have to apply a transition to it by myself because without a transition it will make the content appear immediately. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure about the definition and differences of transition and animation. But animate.css is applying some funky movement to what you see but not actually resizing or moving the element around.